# A delegate is class or a structure

Tags: .net

i really gotta confused ..

1. delegates are class or only a type. ??
2. is it necessary for a delegate to be same as a function or function has to save as   delegate

Please bear me i am new for .net

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx

Comment: A delegate allows you to pass in a block of code around in code e.g. as a parameter to any function.. code as argument vs the usual data as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

Basically Delegates are very similar to function pointers. They are like placeholders for a function. So e.g. if you want to write a class which can be customized to use different kinds of sort functions, you could create a delegate and later on fill it with a certain method.

Comment: similar to function pointer.....one more thing which is coming in mind .can a delegate initialize the static variable or static class

Comment: As I wrote - the delegate is only a placeholder for a method. If the method you call via the delegate creates a class then of course the static members are available. Basically you can do everything via a delegate that you can do when calling a method directly.

Comment: If you are content with my answer check it as being correct :-)